# Capacitive Divider driving DC load

Tags: capacitor

I have a question about a capacitor divider that drives a resistor.
I understand that capacitor dividers only work in dividng AC signals.

[image]

You can see that at the start of the simulation Vo1 is at 0.6V as Vin is ramped up and thus appears as a transient AC to the capacitive divider and so it divides its accordingly to its ratio. Then I switched a resistor on at the output, current flows to the resistor and slowly discharges the cap.

My question is (probably a stupid one) - How come the cap doesn't charge up again to continue to provide the resistor with its current? I know caps don't allow DC but I'm having difficulty understanding how the initial transient allows the resistor to sink current yet the cap cannot charge back up to keep providing the resistor with current.

Comment: After you connect the load resistance, the C1 charging current will start to flow and at the same time, C2 discharging (via load resisatnce) current will also start to flow as well.  And the end you will have a 0V across C2 and Vsup across C1.

Comment: So after connecting the resistor, the C1 charging current flows to the resistor and so does the C2 discharge current. So C2 does not charge up at all?

Comment: Exactly, C2 does not charge up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How come the cap doesn't charge up again to continue to provide the
> resistor with its current?*

Once the resistor has taken all the charge from the lower capacitor and things have settled down, the voltage across that lower capacitor is 0 volts (because it has been discharged by the resistor) and, the full voltage from the pulse is across the upper capacitor.

So now, at this point, there is no current entering the capacitive divider and hence, when you open circuit the resistor, the voltage across the lower capacitor will not change from 0 volts.

So, unless something else changes, when you re-apply the resistor load, it will connect itself to 0 volts (the voltage on the lower capacitor) and no current will flow into the resistor.

Comment: How come when the resistor is still taking current from C1 and C2, why doesn't some of the C1 current go to C2 to charge it up? That's where my confusion is. How come all the C1 current and C2 current must flow through the resistor?

Comment: A current taken from C1 and C2 by a resistor is only flowing into that resistor and not (magically) flowing into C2 to charge it up. The resistor is discharging C2 and increasing the charge into C1. If the resistor's return path were to the top of C1 (as opposed to ground or 0 volts) then the opposite would apply. @SuperConductor47 you should probably [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give their time for free to help.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!